# Filtering results in a given radius

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, users, human-interface-guideline

I have the following structure on the server :
Parent -> child object.

I have around 30-40 parents which each parent has 1-10 childs.

A user can search children at a given point in a given a radius, and then filter with parent list, so only children associated with with the selected parent will show.

Would you expect all the parents to appear in the filtering list or only ones which have children in the search results?

Keep in mind that if only associated parents will show the filtering list will change every time the radius is changed, which might be confusing.
And would your answer be influenced by the number of parents and children?

Comment: Typically, I would answer: show only these parents that have children within the search results, but I feel this case may be specific - could you provide us with some more information, preferably showing us some screenshot or mockup of the system you are refering to?

Comment: OK, so this may be an established information retrieval term, but I don't know it, so I will ask: what do you mean by radius?

Comment: This is not really answerable without an idea of what 'radius'  means for this problem. I'm voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this could be a service for users to find companies with branches closest to where they live.

As a user, I want to find a service closest to me, and I will most likely not care about the company. I'll take the branch location (regardless of what company) closest to me as my first criterion. So, if you provide a drop-down list of companies to filter, I will most likely ignore it. If I'm curious enough, I will peek at the DDL, and if I haven't heard of any of the companies on that DDL, I will regard this filtering as useless. You may provide this capability for users that want a specific company, but don't require it as a criteria.

For each of your search results:

- Include the company name, address of the branch, and distance in the link.
- Provide a short description of the company and/or branch below the link.
- Order by closest first.

This way, you will not have to worry about parent-child confusion, which the end user won't care about anyway.